# Grafana graph not moving dynamically

Tags: spring-boot, influxdb, grafana

I am trying to create a platform which can be used for monitoring purpose of spring boot applications. I have chosen infulxdb as a choice of TSDB and grafana for data visualization.

I have created a solution with spring boot which is able to push data in influxDB in a measurement called heap.

I have configured a datasource in Grafana as well

[image]

Next i have created a dashboard and added a graph panel with metrics as below

[image]

Problem here is everytime i have to see that graph, i have to click on right arrow next to zoomout, graph should move automatically with latest time in focus. It is staying constant, can anyone please suggest what i am missing here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean the auto-refresh option in the time picker in the top right corner? This setting fetches data every x seconds.

[image]

Here is a gif of the graphs updating every 5 seconds (the gif is 15 seconds long):

[image]

Comment: it fetches the data, and if i scroll right i can see the data. but i have to scroll everytime it should keep scrolling on its own, graph should keep scrolling left so i can see latest data everytime.

Comment: You have to scroll right? That sounds really strange. Do you mean the graph panel has a scroll bar? I don't see one in your screenshot above.

Comment: Added a gif showing refresh behavior. I do not have to scroll, the graphs update by themselves. Think I'm missing something here - can you explain more?

Comment: My bad, i had clicked on zoom out so it was basically working within that time frame only, i updated the TimeRange to now. It works perfectly fine. Thanks :)